# Alguém sabe a possível causa do erro "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression"?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um código em jQuery que realizo um evento quando clico em um determinado botão. O problema é que quando esse evento é executado, o console me apresenta o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aquele **a.stand-by-coluna** é um elemento 'a' que eu tenho dentro de uma 'tr'. Esses elementos são criados dinamicamente. Vou deixar o código do evento que faz ocorrer o erro. Não sei se o erro é exatamente nele.

**Código do evento: (Acho que esse código é meio dispensável para resolução da pergunta. Porém postei uma parte do evento, pois é quando ocorre o erro)**

```js
//CÓDIGO PARA QUANDO CLICAR NO BOTÃO 'REABRIR ATIVIDADES' DA COLUNA REABRIR, ENTÃO A ATIVIDADE SERÁ REABERTA
$(document).on("click", ".reabrir-atividade-coluna", function(e) {

  let pegar_tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  let pegar_status = $(pegar_tr).attr('name');
  console.log(pegar_status);


  var elemento = $(this);
  var sts = $(this).attr('name');
  var codigo_empr = $(this).attr('value');

  //VERIFICANDO O STATUS DO CAMPO QUE RECEBERÁ O NOVO STATUS APÓS O CLIQUE NO REABRIR 
  //PASSAR BOTÃO DE CONCLUIDO PARA INICIADO    
  if (sts == "CONCLUIDO") {
    if (data_banco_vencimento >= data_hoje_formatada) {
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO");
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('CONCLUIDO')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('btn-success')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('INICIADO');
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('btn-info');
      //Altera o atributo name do elemento
      elemento.attr('name', 'INICIADO');
      var novo_status = "INICIADO";
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " a.stand-by-coluna").attr('data-status', 'INICIADO');
      var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);
      sts = elemento.attr('name');

      //ACREDITO QUE POSSA ESTAR ACONTECENDO UM POSSÍVEL ERRO AQUI
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'INICIADO');
      // TRECHO ACIMA

      $(this).attr('name', 'INICIADO');
    } else {

      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO_VENCIDO");
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('CONCLUIDO')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('btn-success')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('INICIADO_VENCIDO');
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('btn-warning');
      //Altera o atributo name do elemento
      elemento.attr('name', 'INICIADO_VENCIDO');
      var novo_status = "INICIADO_VENCIDO";
      $("tr." + codigo_emp + " a.stand-by-coluna").attr('data-status', 'INICIADO_VENCIDO');
      var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);
      sts = elemento.attr('name');

      //ACREDITO QUE POSSA ESTAR ACONTECENDO UM POSSÍVEL ERRO AQUI
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'INICIADO_VENCIDO');
      //TRECHO ACIMA É O POSSÍVEL ERRO

      $(this).attr('name', 'INICIADO_VENCIDO');
    }

  }

});
```

**Código de criação do elemento que está apresentando o erro (ele está dentro de um loop).**

```js
//botão stand by
atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;" class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody td-padding">'
atividades += '<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-stand-by" data-placement="top"  class="btn btn-sm btn-light  css-stand-by-coluna stand-by-coluna" data-status="' + valor.STATUS + '" id="' + valor.codigo + '"  value="' + valor.COD + '">'
atividades += '<i class="text-dark fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>'
atividades += '</a>'
atividades += '</td>';
```

**Código de criação do elemento no qual eu clico para ocorrer o evento**

```js
atividades += '<td style="padding:0;text-align:center;" class="th-ocultar-responsivo-tbody td-padding">'
atividades += '<a type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Voltar o Status da atividade para o estado anterior." class="btn btn-sm btn-light css-reabrir reabrir-atividade-coluna" name="' + valor.STATUS + '" value="' + valor.codigo + '">'
atividades += '<i class="text-info fas fa-history"></i>'
atividades += '</a>'
atividades += '</td>';
```

Não coloquei mais código, pois poderiam reclamar da descrição ter ficado muito longa. Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: `codigo_empr` esta retornando um elemento e não o valor deste elemento, tente `codigo_empr.value`

Comment: Só uma dúvida, minha pergunta está mal formulada ao ponto de ser negativada ?

Comment: Não sei o motivo, só a pessoa que negativou poderia lhe informar, mas suponho que pode ser por inumeros motivos, por exemplo, ao invés de copiar o erro você colocou uma print, o quye é um baita exagero, outra coisa, o erro é um pouco evidente e vocÊ só colocou um trecho do código, esperando que adivinhemos a origem do problema. Por isso no HELP do site fala tanto do MCVE, como criar um exemplo minimo e reproduzivel do erro. Espero que ajude a entender. PS: votei para fechar, não leve a mal, mas a sua pergunta é erro de digitação, mesmo assim fiz um esforço para resolver no primeiro comentario.

Comment: Eu não sabia da questão do print do erro. Achava que só print do código fosse 'má formulação da pergunta'. Eu não sabia que o erro era evidente. Pelo menos pra mim não é. Eu coloquei o trecho do código do evento que apresenta o erro, para não deixar a descrição da pergunta muito grande de código (eu não esperava que vocês advinhassem a origem, só quis evitar excessos). Vou tentar fazer o que você falou. Obrigado pelos conselhos, na próxima pergunta eu tento elaborar melhor.

Comment: Eu entendo que você não compreendia e por isso comentei as possibilidade, justamente porque acho importante orientar :) Espero que o primeiro comentário que fiz sobre trocar `codigo_empr` por `codigo_empr.value` tenha resolvido, caso contrário edite a pergunta.

Comment: O codigo_empr está retornando exatamente a numeração que eu precisava. Quando eu dou console.log a numeração presente em codigo_empr aparece pra mim.

Comment: Adicionei na descrição da pergunta o código de criação do botão relacionado ao evento.

Comment: Troque `$(this).attr('value');` por `$(this).val();` e veja se não esta usando essa var com outra coisa, pq me parece que você esta misturando ela.

Comment: Quando eu faço isso, a variável codigo_empr fica vazia. Não é atribuído valor a ela.

Comment: tem algo ai muito errado mesmo, não era para acontecer.

Comment: olá, não me parece uma boa ideia mudar o nome do elemento, deveria usar um data-attibute para isso se quer manter um valor que pode mudar

Comment: Viu, @GuilhermeNascimento , o erro não está tão evidente asim. ;/

Comment: Eu fico com medo de colocar código grande na pergunta e a galera reclamar.

Comment: @Petherson justamente o que eu disse, falta um trecho do código e a parte que falei que é evidente é que está sendo passado um elemento HTML ao invés do seu valor. Por isso citei o MCVE (como criar um exemplo minimo executavel) que é citado no help do site, claro que depois do seu edit a pergunta melhorou, mas antes disto, no momento que comentei a primeira vez, ainda não tinha clareza do código. Estou apenas lhe orientando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analisando seu código, pude reparar que o erro está na digitação do nome da variável "codigo_empr" nas linhas marcadas abaixo.

```js
if (sts == "CONCLUIDO") {
    if (data_banco_vencimento >= data_hoje_formatada) {
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO");
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('CONCLUIDO')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('btn-success')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('INICIADO');
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('btn-info');
      //Altera o atributo name do elemento
      elemento.attr('name', 'INICIADO');
      var novo_status = "INICIADO";
      *****$("tr." + codigo_emp + " a.stand-by-coluna").attr('data-status', 'INICIADO');*****
      var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);
      sts = elemento.attr('name');

      //ACREDITO QUE POSSA ESTAR ACONTECENDO UM POSSÍVEL ERRO AQUI
      $(this).parent().parent().attr('name', 'INICIADO');
      // TRECHO ACIMA

      $(this).attr('name', 'INICIADO');
    } else {

      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").html("INICIADO_VENCIDO");
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('CONCLUIDO')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").removeClass('btn-success')
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('INICIADO_VENCIDO');
      $("tr." + codigo_empr + " button.reabriratividade").addClass('btn-warning');
      //Altera o atributo name do elemento
      elemento.attr('name', 'INICIADO_VENCIDO');
      var novo_status = "INICIADO_VENCIDO";
      ****$("tr." + codigo_emp + " a.stand-by-coluna").attr('data-status', 'INICIADO_VENCIDO');****
      var reabrir = reabrirAtividade(sts, novo_status, codigo_empr);
      sts = elemento.attr('name');
```

nas duas linhas que demarquei com asteriscos, você usou o nome "codigo_emp" que não foi declarado ou inicializado em momento algum no seu código. 
Verifique e veja se resolve.

Comment: Puts, Denied. Era isso mesmo. Acho que eu havia copiado esse trecho do código de outro local e, como a variável tem o nome parecido, eu acabei deixando passar despercebido. Erro bobo. Eu eu desde ontem procurando o erro no código todo. As variáveis, nessa parte do código, tinham que ser todas codigo_empr. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

o erro está na maneira que é pego o valor da váriavel `pegar_status`

se for input use

```js
let pegar_status = $(pegar_tr).val();
                                ↑
```

se for outro tipo de elemento uso

```js
let pegar_status = $(pegar_tr).data('value');
                                ↑
```

para essa segunda maneira, você vai precisar definir o 'date' assim

```html
<elemento data-value="valor">
           ↑
```

Comment: amanhã vou tentar do seu jeito. Mas me explica uma coisa. Pq não posso pegar pelo attr('name') ? E outra coisa, quando eu dou uma console.log na variável pegar_status, aparece o valor que eu quero armazenado nela. Ou seja, o name está sendo pego daquele jeito. Eu sei que dá pra utilizar data-atribute, porém não sei o problema em utilizar o name.

Comment: A função attr está sendo depreciada, pode ser esse o erro, tente com .prop('abc')

Comment: Mudei e não adiantou, mas acredito que não seja esse o problema, Guilherme, pois o attr funciona no código todo. Acredito que o erro seja na parte do código onde vou marcar lá na pergunta.